# Trigger Help: Update Custom Email Field based on Value in Lookup Field (Lookup to User) Using Trigger

Tags: trigger, governorlimits, bulkification

I am new to Apex and would like to practice updating a custom email field which derives its value based on a custom lookup field.  I understand this can be done with a simple formula, but want to practice creating triggers.

My example is, I have a custom object ‘Position__c’ with a lookup field ‘Hiring_Manager__c’ (lookup to User). I want to be able to populate ‘managers_email_address__c’ (custom email field) based on the ‘hiring_manager__c’  lookup field, which will pull the EMAIL address from the User record.

Here’s where I have gotten so far with error "Compile Error: Variable does not exist: hiring_manager__c at line 3 column 7":

```
Trigger updateEmail on Position__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<Id, User> newMap = [SELECT ID, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :hiring_manager__c];

for (Position__c p : Trigger.new){

User u = newMap.get(p.hiring_manager__c);

if (u != null) {

    p.managers_email_address__c = u.Email;

     }
  }            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build an Id collection and query on that. You should investigate handler architecture and one trigger per object best practice. Regardless, change:

```
Map<Id, User> newMap = [SELECT ID, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :hiring_manager__c];
```

to:

```
Set<Id> managerIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Position__c record : trigger.new)
    managerIds.add(record.Manager_Email__c);
Map<Id, User> managers = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT ID, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :managerIds]);
```

I would also recommend working on concise field names and clear the value if the lookup is blank:

```
record.Manager_Email__c = !managers.containsKey(record.Hiring_Manager__c) ?
    null : managers.get(record.Hiring_Manager__c).Email;
```

Comment: Adrian & sfdcfox - Thank you so much.  I really appreciate the help.  I had to make a few tweeks to account for the correct API names in the proposed solution, but now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final trigger that is successfully updating the custom email field:

```
Trigger updateEmail on Position__c (before insert, before update) {

Set<Id> managerIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Position__c record : trigger.new)
    managerIds.add(record.hiring_manager__c);
Map<Id, User> managers = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT ID, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :managerIds]);

    for (Position__c p : Trigger.new){

User u = managers.get(p.hiring_manager__c);

if (u != null) {

    p.managers_email_address__c = u.Email;

        }
    }            
}
```